# $Z[1/p]$ projective resolution

Tags: abstract-algebra

Denote $Z[1/p]=\{\sum_{i\in Z}a_i p^i\vert a_i\in Z\}$ where $i$ is allowed to be negative integers and the sum is finite sum. Clearly $\oplus_N Z\to Z[1/p]$ is surjection map by $(\dots, a_{-1},a_0,a_1,\dots,)\to \sum_i a_ip^i$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ How do I describe the kernel as the free module? Since $\oplus_N Z$ is free, the kernel is a submodule which has to be free. I can certainly clear denominator of $\sum_{i\geq -k}a_i p^i=0$ which reduces to study of relation of $\sum_{i\geq 0}a_{i-k}p^i$. This requires $p\mid a_{i-k}$, $p^2\mid a_{i-k+1},\dots$. How should I describe this kernel. The reason to look at this projective resolution is to look at $Ext^1_Z(Z[1/p],Z)$ as $Ext^i=0$ for $i\geq 2$.

Comment: The kernel is generated by $px_i = x_{i+1}$ if $x_i$ is the $i$th generator in $\oplus_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Max I thought it was that. However, this is not $p-$adic sense convergence. WLOG, I need $\sum_{i\geq 0}a_{i}p^i=0$. I can deduce division condition. However, I do not see $px_i=x_{i+1}$ condition here. Why this is the case? Take $a_0+a_{-1}/p+a_{-2}/p^2=0$ for example. I have $p\mid a_{-2}$. So $a_{-2}/p^2$ can be absorbed into $a_{-1}/p$. This implies that the image should at least 2 different representations. $(a_{-2},a_{-1},a_0)$ and $(a'_{-1},a_0)$. How do I see the relation fulfills the condition here?

Comment: Equivalently $\phi : \mathbb{Z}[x]/(px-1)\to \mathbb{Z}[1/p],\phi(\sum_{i=0}^N a_i x^i) = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} a_ip^{-i}$ is an isomorphism, so the kernel of $\mathbb{Z}[x]\to \mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ is $(px-1) \mathbb{Z}[x]$

Comment: @reuns Ah. Thanks. I did forget to use this trick.